# Can I stop a UITableViewCell from autoresizing its subviews?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with custom background images in each cell.  The bottom cell has a taller image that the rest, because it contains a shadow.  That means I have to extend the height of the last cell in a section to be taller than normal.

When I do this, the contents of the `UITableViewCell` look like they are resting at the bottom of the cell instead of the middle (because the visual cell is shorter than the actual cell).  Is there a way that I can position my content from the top instead of the center, and not have the `UITableViewCell` resize it when a cell becomes the bottom cell (due to deleting or whatever)?

Setting the autoresizing mask on the labels to have a static top boundary doesn't work, nor does turning off `autoresizesSubviews` on the cell.

I also thought about simply making all the cells the same height and turning off `clipsToBounds` on the background image, except the background image is a stretchable image both horizontally and vertically, and needs to be able to resize based on the height of the contents of the cell.

Any other ideas that don't involve a hackish method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having a similar problem ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526910)). The solution was to override layoutSubviews in my custom table view cell class *and do nothing*.

Comment: THANK you! Finally, a real answer!

Comment: A call to [super layoutSubviews] can cause this problem to happen. The 'do nothing' is key!

Comment: Hello all, this is an iOS developer from 2014 building with iOS 7 and this shit is still happening. I can't believe it.

Answer (score 2):

Try *tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:* inside your tableViewController. Remember to include the UITableViewDelegate as a protocol.

Check out [Apple iPhone Reference Library: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) for limitations and what you can return.

Edit:
Okay, knowing more about your question try

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no thanks.  I'm already using that to return the height of the row (it has to be BIGGER for the bottom row, because the image is bigger).  If I return the same size for all rows, the bottom row looks too small.

Comment: You can select a row using the IndexPath to only resize the last row only and leave the rest of your rows resizing correctly. An if(indexPath.row == [array count]) return 100 else return 50; might solve your problem of the cell auto-resizing.

Comment: No, no, no.  I AM ALREADY doing this, because the last row needs to be larger than the others, but VISUALLY it needs to look the same (hence I am using a stretchable image).  The problem of autoresizing isn't that the cell itself changes height, but that it moves its subviews around, when moving in and out of edit mode, for example.

Comment: Oh, now I know what you're doing. I can see that you're getting frustrated, but the question wasn't succinct. Anyway I believe you're looking for "tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:" where you return a boolean for the row you don't wish to indent while editing.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom cell in a table view is just clipped visually, technically not resized since the `frame` value is the same internally.

I think you mean that you want your text to be vertically aligned with the top of the cell, right?

If that's it, you can achieve this by resizing the `UILabel` containing your text to have the same vertical size of the included text, and making sure the label is flush against the top of the cell - or as close as you like (it looks better with a few pixels' worth of padding).

How do you know what size the text is?  You can use the handy-dandy `sizeWithFont:...` method on `NSString` (technically it's not in the original class definition, but [added later by `UIKit`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html)).  Here is some sample code:

```
NSString *myString = @"lorem ipsum dolor yadda";
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
CGSize myStringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:myFont 
                           constrainedToSize:textLabel.frame.size
                               lineBreakMode:textLabel.lineBreakMode];

textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, /* Or whichever origin you want. */
                             textLabel.frame.size.width, myStringSize.height);
```

Comment: My problem is not sizing it; it's making sure it stays that size.  The label is the standard UITableViewCell.textLabel, and no matter where I position it, it seems to be moving back to its own location any time the Cell's transform changes (i.e. turning edit mode on/off)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an automatic solution for this one.  I have instead overridden several functions (`textLabel`, `detailTextLabel`, `setAccessoryView:`) to use my own labels that are autoresized how I want them to be.

I also had to override the `willTransitionToState:` method and delve into the implementation specifics to get the add/delete and delete confirmation buttons to move where I want them to.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I ran into it searching for the same problem.

Overriding layoutSubviews may hide the problem but it doesn't fix it nor work in every situation.

My guess is that several here have added labels to their custom cells using the same names.  This causes the behavior that position is incorrect until scrolled as there's a name conflict going on. Here's where I found this. [dequeued UITableViewCell has incorrect layout until scroll (using autolayout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995573/dequeued-uitableviewcell-has-incorrect-layout-until-scroll-using-autolayout)

Redoing my IBOutlets with different names than the standard labels fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a UIImageView only in the cell and it would resize it to the full cell size no matter what. Tried all the solutions mentioned here. 
What is weird is that I have another more complex cell, where I have a UIImageView+UIPageControl+UILabel+UIButton.. It only seems to behave badly when there is a single UIImageView.

My workaround was to place a UIButton instead of an image, and have the image as the background image of the button.