# How to calculate the height of a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, core-text

I'm trying to set the UITableViewCell's Height depending on the height of a UILabel.
My problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682208/set-uitableviewcells-height-depending-on-the-height-of-a-uilabel).
But the OC code in that answer seems to been deprecated now(I'm not sure, just can't find it).
I'm using the following code to calculate the height of the label.

```
extension String {
    // the length of text in one line
    func size(ofFont font: UIFont) {
        return (self as NSString).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])
}
```

In `cellForRow:` method:

```
let size = text.size(ofFont: font)
let height = ceil(size.width/(UIScreen.main.bounds.width))*size.height
```

But it would be additional break line if the last word is too long to display in one line.
 So, here comes the bug.
Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: better use automatic dimensions.

Comment: Why not using dynamic cell sizing?

Comment: you can set constraint it's really easy

Comment: see here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43535950/6479530 , Replace Text View to `UILabel` and `label.numberOfLines = 0` .

Comment: Thank you guy, I didn't know automatic dimensions before. It's really awkward.

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S It helps, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In Swift 3**

set **BackgroundView** Constraint like **leading, trailing,top,bottom,** please show image.

[image]

set **UILabel** Constraint like **leading, trailing, top, bottom**

and set it's property **numberOfLines = 0**

[image]

and after that your viewController class ViewDidLoad method write this code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //dynamic tablview
        yourTablview.estimatedRowHeight = 83.0
        yourTablview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

I hope it's work for you.

Comment: My answer is helpful then please give upvote and Right

Comment: Thank you, I already set the constraints to the label. `UITableViewAutomaticDimension `  is all I need. Thank you again for your  detailed answer.

Comment: I got new a problem and need your help. The height of the collection view will be 0 if I set UITableViewAutomaticDimension. The collection view works well if I set a fixed height to the cell. The collection view is initialed from the storyboard and setup in customized TableViewCell.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```

And you should also set `numberOfLines`

```
cell.label.numberOfLines = 0
```

Don't forget to set constraints on all sides

Comment: Thank you, `UITableViewAutomaticDimension ` is all I need.

Comment: I got a new problem and need your help. The height of the collection view will be 0 if I set UITableViewAutomaticDimension. The collection view works well if I set a fixed height to the cell. The collection view is initialed from the storyboard and setup in customized TableViewCell. Thank you.

Comment: @CallOfOrange  Let's solve that problem in [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151072/phyber-and-calloforange)