# dequeued UITableViewCell has incorrect layout until scroll (using autolayout)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass which has had autolayout constraints applied to it in Interface Builder.  The cell contains multiple views, including a `UITextField`.

Relevantly, the size of the `UITextField` is constrained such that there is default horizontal spacing between it and the next view.

The cell is instantiated like follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProgressCell";
    ProgressCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath]

    cell.textField.text = @"Some string that is different for each cell";

    return cell;
}
```

When the cell first appears, the `UITextField` overruns the correct frame, and appears behind the `UIView` to its right.  However, when I scroll the cell off screen, pause, and then scroll back, the text is truncated correctly.

An example is shown below (at the second edit).

I have tried calling `[cell setNeedsLayout]` and `[cell setNeedsDisplay]` for the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, as well as performing them after a delay.  Neither is effective.

What is scrolling off screen doing that is causing the cell to appear correctly, and how can I either replicate this or fix the underlying issue?

EDIT:

Calling

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

in order to reload the cell, appears to cause the layout to appear correctly first time.

However, it now *breaks* (occasionally) on scrolling (ie, when scrolling back up, the layout constraints are now not applied correctly).

Calling `[cell setNeedsLayout]` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` appears not to fix this issue.

EDIT2:

The top cell, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOBS8.jpg), appeared correctly (as the bottom cell does) until I scrolled down the screen.  It since disappeared.

This reflects the problem as of the first edit - it's the second rendering that is the problem (makes me think that it might have something to do with reusing the cell?)

Comment: Are you getting any warnings about the constraints in the console?

Comment: Can you include some screenshots?

Comment: @rdelmar I wrote up my Autolayout category (didnt we discuss that earlier?) if you're interested: http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/02/20/creating-individual-layout-constraints/

Comment: I've uploaded an example image here: http://imgur.com/a/IKv0Z.  There are no constraint warnings in the console @rdelmar - and they're all set up through IB, so they should be valid.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with those constraints. I tried to duplicate your problem, but mine truncated long text without scrolling. If you make the width constraint = instead of >= does that help? Can you just delete that one (it will depend on what you have for the other 2 objects to the right)?

Comment: I've tried making the width equal, deleting the constraint, and even ignoring autolayout altogether and setting the autoresizing masks.  None of those ideas fixed the issue :/  Even with a fixed width, if I set the textLabel's background colour, I can see that it is taking up the entire cell.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you name a property on a `UITableViewCell` subclass `textLabel` or `defaultTextLabel`, then IB will ignore the constraints you have specified and override them with default ones, with no warnings issued.

This is the case even on cells designed in IB with the Custom style, which have no visible `textLabel` or `detailTextLabel` properties.

This also happen if add a property of type `UIImageView` property on a `UITableViewCell` subclass and name it `imageView`.

Comment: The same goes for the "imageView" property as well.

Comment: This answer needs to be promoted into the UITableViewCell class reference, I just wasted 4 hours of my life. its 4 in the morning...

Comment: Thank you so much.  You just saved me several hours of my life.

Comment: I wish Interface Builder or the compiler gave you a warning about inadvertently overriding these Property names.

Comment: The same goes for UIImageView properties named "maskView" as well.

Answer (score 8):

In accordance to this [multiple lines `UILabel` GitHub issue](https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8/issues/22#issuecomment-89853337), this is a lingering iOS bug.

I found that in iOS 9+, this situation mostly occurs in editing mode, with much unpredictability.

The following workaround only partially works: it requires redrawing the `UITableView` twice, and still does not cover all scenarios.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.setNeedsLayout()
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

---

**Notes:**

- Using `UITextView` is a great alternative to multiple line `UILabel`, without the bug. `UITextView` does not exhibit any of the `IULabel` other oddities either, like [alignment errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35440342/218152) or [flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35260912/218152).
- There is also an alternative solution on [SO-25947146](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25967370/218152), which did not work for me but is worth mentioning.
- Seems to occur prominently when `self.tableView.editing` is `true`
- Using low values for `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` reduces the occurrence
- Demonstration of the bug on [SwiftArchitect/TableViewControllerRowHeightBug](https://gist.github.com/SwiftArchitect/c2f1bea2c575e3dadf09) gist

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I call method tableView.reloadData() in viewDidAppear and the layout appear correctly

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This approach was already suggested in a previous answer 5 years ago.

Comment: @miken32 Because I have tried to write it on viewDidLoad and got no work so...