# Multiple UILabels inside a self sizing UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout, ios8

In this iOS 8 app I'm creating, I have a tableview and I need them to be self resizing. I implemented it using Auto Layout and it works. Almost. Here's how it looks now.

[image]

There are 3 labels inside a cell. Main label which has the lorem ipsum text. Subtitle which has the string of numbers (Those are two separate labels. Might be confusing because they have the same color.) Then the third label with the small black text.

The first label resized itself correctly with no problem and the second label moves up and down accordingly. But the problem is with the third small label. As you can see, its not resizing itself to fit all the text.

Now there's a weird thing happening. I turn it landscape and here's it is.

[image]

Since there is space the label is displaying the entire text its supposed to. Fine. Then I turn it back to portrait.

[image]

Now the small label has resized itself to fit all its text but it overflows the cells boundaries. I tried making the cell bigger but it didn't work. Since this is self sizing cells, I don't think that's the correct way even.

I'm not getting any errors or even warning on my auto layout constraints either.

[image]

I have set these two lines of code in the `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Can anyone please tell me what I might be doing wrong here?

Since its difficult to answer just by looking at images and I don't have any more code to post beside the above snippet, I uploaded a runnable Xcode project demonstrating the issue [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3zslfl77s54zga/Layout.zip?dl=0). (There are 2 custom cells. Basically its the same cell just the height is increased in the second one.)

I've been fiddling with auto layout constraints but I can't seem to get this working. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

---

**UPDATE:**

With the help of this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout) I found some helpful pointers. According to it, each subview should have constraints that pin  all its sides and there should be constraints that goes from top to  bottom which helps auto layout to calculate the height of the cell. In my original post, I had vertical spaces between each label so I think that's the reason auto layout couldn't calculate the proper height.

So I made some changes.

- I reduced the vertical space between labels to 0 and set the Vertical space constraints between top and middle labels and middle and bottom labels.
- I added leading, top, trailing constraints to the top label.
- Leading and trailing to the middle label.
- Leading, bottom, trailing to the bottom label.

Now here's another weird part. When I first run it, the bottom label cropping issue is still there.

[image]

But if I rotate the device to landscape and turn it back to portrait, all the all the cells are resized properly to fit both labels!

[image]

Still can't figure out why this doesn't happen at first though. Updated Xcode project is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfdzlpadaetlek4/SelfSizingCellsIssue.zip?dl=0).

Comment: The table is finding it too difficult to estimate the exact height of the text in your labels before the view appears, but it is doing pretty well all the same. I found that if you move tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100 to viewDidAppear then this solves the problem you're seeing

Comment: ... or rather, it seems the table is using the estimated height as an excuse to not do an exact calculation on first loading the table. But if estimatedRowHeight is moved as described this solves the problem you're seeing. Removing it altogether creates redraw issues on rotate.

Comment: @GoodbyeStackOverflow I did as you suggested but I'm facing some issues. [This is how it looks when you run it](http://i.imgur.com/1CNGVgR.png) and [when you scroll down](http://i.imgur.com/lH7hasO.png). I also applied the same to my second example and [this is the result](http://i.imgur.com/AWg9Yib.png). Looks good in the first 3 cells but note that it's gotten messed up in the last cell.

Comment: @Isuru XCode project is not there. Can you please upload it again ? I am working on the same kind of things.

Comment: @Hiren Sorry, I don't have that project anymore. It was just a temporary project.

Comment: @Isuru I have solved using the tutorial and your comment :)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The issue here is with the multi-line labels' `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property. This is the property that tells the label when it should word wrap. It must be set correctly in order for each label's `intrinsicContentSize` to have the correct height, which is ultimately what Auto Layout will be using to determine the cell's height.

Xcode 6 Interface Builder introduced a new option to have this property set to *Automatic*. Unfortunately, there are some serious bugs (as of Xcode 6.2/iOS 8.2) where this is not set correctly/automatically when loading a cell from a nib or Storyboard.

In order to work around this bug, we need to have the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` set to be exactly equal to the final width of the label once it is displayed in the table view. Effectively, we want to do the following before returning the cell from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
cell.nameLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(cell.nameLabel.frame)
cell.idLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(cell.idLabel.frame)
cell.actionsLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(cell.actionsLabel.frame)
```

The reason that just adding this code alone doesn't work is because when these 3 lines of code execute in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, we are using the width of each label to set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` -- however, if you check the width of the labels at this point in time, the label width is totally different from what it will end up being once the cell is displayed and its subviews have been laid out.

How do we get the label widths to be accurate at this point, so that they reflect their final width? Here's the code that makes it all come together:

```
// Inside of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, after dequeueing the cell

cell.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), height: 99999)
cell.contentView.bounds = cell.bounds
cell.layoutIfNeeded()

cell.nameLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(cell.nameLabel.frame)
cell.idLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(cell.idLabel.frame)
cell.actionsLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(cell.actionsLabel.frame)
```

OK, so what are we doing here? Well, you'll notice there are 3 new lines of code added. First, we need to set this table view cell's width so that it matches the actual width of the table view (this assumes the table view has already been laid out and has its final width, which should be the case). We're effectively just making the cell width correct early, since the table view is going to do this eventually.

You'll also notice that we're using `99999` for the height. What's that about? That is a simple workaround for the problem discussed in detail [here](https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout/issues/16), where if your constraints require more vertical space than the current height of the cell's contentView, you get a constraint exception that doesn't actually indicate any real problem. The height of the cell or any of its subviews doesn't actually matter at this point, because we only care about getting the final widths for each label.

Next, we make sure that the contentView of the cell has the same size as we just assigned to the cell itself, by setting the contentView's bounds to equal the cell's bounds. This is necessary because all of the auto layout constraints you have created are relative to the contentView, so the contentView must be the correct size in order for them to get solved correctly. Just setting the cell's size manually does **not** automatically size the contentView to match.

Finally, we force a layout pass on the cell, which will have the auto layout engine solve your constraints and update the frames of all the subviews. Since the cell & contentView now have the same widths they will at runtime in the table view, the label widths will also be correct, which means that the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` set to each label will be accurate and will cause the label to wrap at the right time, which of course means the labels' heights will be set correctly when the cell is used in the table view!

This is definitely an Apple bug in UIKit that we have to workaround for now (so please do [file bug reports](https://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple so they prioritize a fix!).

One final note: this workaround will run into trouble if your table view cell's `contentView` width doesn't extend the full width of the table view, for example when there is a section index showing on the right. In this case, you'll need to make sure that you manually take this into account when setting the width of the cell -- you may need to hardcode these values, something like:

```
let cellWidth = CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds) - kTableViewSectionIndexWidth
cell.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cellWidth, height: 99999)
```

Comment: @Isuru The unsatisfiable constraint exceptions you're getting after forcing a layout pass on the cell are likely not a real issue, and can be worked around easily. See [this thread](https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout/issues/16) for a complete discussion of the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I spent 2 days trying everything I could find to get my labels to resize correctly. The weird thing was that some did resize, but other cell designs did not. I could not find a difference in the constraints or other settings. However, your solution worked great. I did create a UILabel subclass and put the preferredMaxLayoutWidth setting inside setBounds to avoid hard references to the UILabels in the table view controller.

Comment: Great post. Thank you. It really helped me out and now my labels behave as intended

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Forcing `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` has unfortunately undesirable effects, such as breaking orientation change, and requires even more code. A **0 lines of code** alternative is to use `UITextView` instead of multiple line `UILabel`.

Comment: please read my comment below for @fogisland answer. Works for 8.1 and above

Comment: Thanks alot @smileyborg this worked for me like a magical spell. Though one thing, we have to use this for all the labels that are there in the cell vertical.

Answer (score 50):

I met the same issue as you and I found a simple solution to resolve it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     // dequeue cell...

     // do autolayout staffs...or if the autolayout rule has been set in xib, do nothing

     [cell layoutIfNeeded];

     return cell;
}
```

And the self-sizing worked well. In my code, I laid two labels in vertical, both of them are dynamic height. The height of cell is correctly set to contain the two labels.

Comment: This the the best answer. The accepted answer of setting preferredMaxLayoutWidth still has issues in my experience.

Comment: sheesh, i looked all over for an answer. all these complicated, inelegant solutions. here, one line of code. done...

Comment: Unfortunately I've found that this did not work for me, while smileyborg's solution did.

Comment: as of iOS8.3 this resolves layout issues when the multiline label is pinned between two other items.

Comment: it worked for me for 8.1 adding this line cell.layoutIfNeeded() in above func. rest was already working

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you don't have any errors with your constraints as others have suggested, this problem seems to stem from using a UILabel that allows multiple lines in conjunction with a UITableViewCellAccessory. When iOS lays out the cell and determines the height, it does not account for the offset change in width that occurs because of this accessory, and you get truncation where you wouldn't expect to.

Assuming you want the UILabel to extend the full width of the content view, I wrote up a method that fixes this for all font sizes

```
-(void)fixWidth:(UILabel *)label forCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
    float offset = 0;
    switch ([cell accessoryType]) {
        case UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark:
            offset = 39.0;
            break;
        case UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton:
            offset = 47.0;
            break;
        case UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton:
            offset = 67.0;
            break;
        case UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator:
            offset = 33.0;
            break;
        case UITableViewCellAccessoryNone:
            offset = 0;
            break;
    }
    [label setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:CGRectGetWidth([[self tableView]frame]) - offset - 8];
}
```

Simply put this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    #Setup the cell
    ...
    // Fix layout with accessory view
    [self fixWidth:[cell label] forCell:cell];
    return cell;
}
```

Do this for any labels that are going to have multiple lines to adjust the width properly and then recalculate the appropriate heights. This works with dynamic font sizes as well.

Like smileyborg had mentioned, if you weren't using the full width of the contentView you could reference the constraints and subtract them from the width as well.

Edit: I previously was running 'layoutIfNeeded' on the cell but this was creating performance issues and didn't seem to be needed anyway. Removing it hasn't caused any problems for me.

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems here.

1/ Right now, using Visual Format Language, your cell's vertical constraints can be translated like this:

```
Cell: "V:|-(10)-[nameLabel]-(67)-|"
```

Then, you set a second group of constraints:

```
Cell: "V:|-(10)-[nameLabel]-(8)-[pnrLabel]-(2)-[actionsLabel]"
```

Those two groups of constraints can't mix well and will reveal their ambiguity with your second problem.

2/ For some reasons, `actionsLabel` is limited to one line when you launch your app. Then, when you rotate your device to landscape mode, `actionsLabel` accepts to be displayed with two lines or more. Then, when you rotate your device back to portrait mode, `actionsLabel` keeps displaying two lines or more. But, because `actionsLabel` is not really part of your cell's height constraints, it overlap your cell's boundaries.

If you want to solve all those problems, I recommend first that you rebuild your xib file from scratch. This will cure your `actionsLabel` strange behavior (two lines or more only when you rotate your device).

Then, you will have to define your constraints like this:

```
Cell: "V:|-(10)-[nameLabel(>=21)]-(8)-[pnrLabel(>=21)]-(2)-[actionsLabel(>=21)]-(10)-|"
```

Of course, you can define other minimum height constraints for you labels than `(>=21)`. In the same way, your bottom margin can be set to another value than `-(10)-`.

**Addendum**

In order to answer your question, I created a simple project with the previous constraints pattern in my .xib file. The following image may help you build your own constraints.

[image]

Comment: Great, concise answer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I managed to get it working but there's a slight problem. Since the width for these labels are fixed, when you turn the screen landscape they don't adjust to fill the extra space. Is there a way to counter this? Adding Trailing Space to Superview on those labels don't seem to work.

Comment: I've set width constraints for each label in my test project for testing purpose. In your app, don't set width constraints but set Trailing Space to Superview margins contraints for each label. Don't set width constraints AND Trailing Space to Superview margins contraints for each label at the same time: you have to make a choice between one or the other.

Comment: @POB I tried that but removing the width constraints make it look like [this](http://i.imgur.com/2iwo8TX.png). [Here](http://i.imgur.com/Py8MByI.png) is my current auto layout view.

Comment: No, you are right. It's not working when using trailing space to superview margins contraints instead of width constraints... I try to find why.

Comment: I was reading [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout) article and picked up some points (check out the areas with green background). And I made _some_ progress but not quite there yet. According to it, each subview should have constraints that pin all its sides and there should be constraints that goes from top to bottom which helps auto layout to calculate the height of the cell. In that tutorial's example project, it has vertical spacing between labels set to 0.

Comment: So I made some changes. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfdzlpadaetlek4/SelfSizingCellsIssue.zip?dl=0)'s my changed code. Now when you run it first, still the bottom label cropping issue is there but once you turn it landscape and back to portrait, all the [cells are resized properly to fit both the labels](http://i.imgur.com/cTUONNb.png)! Still can't figure out why this doesn't happen at first.

Comment: @POB Finally managed to fix it thanks to 
@smileyborg! Please see [this](https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8/issues/7) github issue.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the very easy and elegant looking solution of "fogisland" - and it did not work. Luckily I found out that one additional line makes it work in all directions. Just tell the system that you not only suggest a new layout (`layoutIfNeeded`), you explicitly ask for it (`setNeedLayout`)

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
return cell
```