# iOS 7/8 UITableView Cell: Two UILabels with dynamic height with auto layout for variable row height

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, autolayout

So I am able to set up dynamic height sizing with auto layout when I have only one label that changes the height based on the length of the string.
My problem is that if I add another UILabel that should do the same, things don't work out.

I am setting both the Content Hugging priority and the Compression Resistance to 1000 for both == I get warnings of ambiguity

If I set the Content Hugging (Vertical) for the second UILabel to 999 or 250 then it works great but only if the second label has 2 or more line. If the second label is blank or has only one line, the heightForRowAtIndexPath systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize height returns large values, and the cells have large blank spaces.

I also played around with the Intrinsic Size: Default or Placeholder(with couple of heights and widths) but it does not help either.

Anyone any suggestions what can be done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got it working finally. The solution was for me to explicitly set the Preferred Width to the current frame width.
So basically checking the Explicit check mark in the Label > Preferred Width in the Size Inspector.

ref: http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout
download the sample code and see the storyboard setup.

Comment: So was your UILabel of a fixed width?

Comment: No, I support various device sizes, so the width varies based on that.

Comment: For me, the missing element was setting the Content Hugging and Content Compression Resistance Priority for both my cell's title and subtitle labels as demonstrated in the Ray Wenderlich tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the wenderlich article! It  worked almost instantaneously. Before I tried to wrap my head around this for several days with searching the internet...

Comment: does dynamic cell height works when using NIAttributed label?
I cant make it work using  NIAttributedLabel but working perfectly in UILabel

pls help

Comment: GOD! I've been pulling my hair on this same issue for over a year now! Today I decided I will fix this and while searching found this thread and you have no idea how happy I am to finally be able to solve this!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH @Zsolt

Answer (score 1):

For me it took a combination of several things.

- Besides setting the content hugging and resistance correct
- I had to make a subclass of UILabel to handle the preferredMaxLayoutWidth of the label
- and correct a bug in the intrinsicContentSize as well

The UILabel subclass ended up looking like this:

```
@implementation LabelDynamicHeight

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.size.width;

    [super layoutSubviews];
}

- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    [super setBounds:bounds];

    if (self.numberOfLines == 0)
    {
        CGFloat boundsWidth = CGRectGetWidth(bounds);
        if (self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != boundsWidth)
        {
            self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = boundsWidth;
            [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        }
    }
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    CGSize size = [super intrinsicContentSize];

    if (self.numberOfLines == 0)
    {
        // There's a bug where intrinsic content size may be 1 point too short
        size.height += 1;
    }

    return size;
}

@end
```

Besides this calling layoutIfNeeded on the cell before getting the height in `tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:` made the constraints to be ready before using the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` method on the contentView. Looking like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:( UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = ...;
    CGFloat height = cell.frame.size.height;
    if (cell.dynamicHeight)
    {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/26351692/1840269
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
        height = cell.frame.size.height;

        CGSize size = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
        if (size.height > height)
            height = size.height;
    }
    return height;
}
```

References:

- Preferred for content hugging and resistance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16281229/1840269
- Description of the preferredMaxLayoutWidth manipulation: https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox/
- Inspiration for the UILabel subclass with the intrinsicContentSize fix: https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8/issues/7

Answer (score 0):

For me setting content hugging priority and content compression resistance priority lower to one of the element worked just as expected.