# How can I set a multiline UILabel inside UITableCell on Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, swift3, multiline

I am trying to set a multiline `UILabel`, inside an `UITableCell`.

That `UILabel` has a proportional `width` taking as reference the screen of the device (with a multiplier). The text inside of it can change so I need to fit on the `UILabel` being able to multiline when the width of the text is higher than the space of the `UILabel` width.

I tried using:

```
myLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
myLabel.sizeToFit()
```

but it is always displayed on one line truncating the text that overflows the `UILabel` width.

How can I make my UILabel to be multiline?

**EDIT:** I cannot put breaklines to my text because I retrieve my texts from my database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use tableview auto dimension propert and estimated row height

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638550/two-uilabels-on-uitable-with-dynamic-height/37638748#37638748

Comment: @Rajat Thank you! Finally I got it changing the height of the row of the UITableCell.

Comment: Happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to make my multiline UILabel adding this code:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0
```

and reducing the `multiplier` value. It seems that the text could not fit on the height of the `UITableCell`.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines are necessary for calculating the cell height automatically. Put these in viewDidLoad.

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a label to switch from one line to multiple lines, you either have to specify line breaks in the text of the string with \n or newline char, or you can set constraints for the width of the label, or you can set leading and trailing constraints for the label. If one of those methods is complete, the label will go to as many lines as it takes to hit the max number of lines or infinite if set to 0.

Comment: I cannot set linebreaks because I retrieve my texts from database and I do not want a fixed width for my label.

Comment: Then you need to give it leading and trailing constraints or a leading/trailing relative frame.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I got it adding a new height to the row of the cell.