# UITableViewAutomaticDimension doesn't work for cell that contains tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have `cell` that contains `tableView`. I need this `tableView` to achieve `datePicker` expand behavior like this:

[image]

but instead of it i have this:

[image]

My code pretty simple. In both `tableView`s i set `estimatedRowHeight` and `rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` (in this situation i had result that second gif show. The expected result (first git) achieved by manually set `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to specific height value). But i have result that i don't expected.
Also when i run the app i have the following warning:

> [Warning] Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.

Why this happens? And can get this work by not adding new overhead code (for example, i believe `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` will correct work if i do some magic with `intrinsic size`).

P.S. Here is [the demo project](https://github.com/pacification/demoproject).

Comment: [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
 self.MainviewHight_Constrain.constant = give your tableview hight 
  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            Isshowsubmenu = NO;
         
        }]; set this all in one button click method .

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` you need to set the constraints of all the elements of your cell from, top, left, bottom, right. If you are not doing do then you will get the warning which you are showing in your question.

Comment: All constraints have already set before i posted this question. Looks like this is not the reason.

Comment: @pacification you need to set the constraint from all the 4 sides check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638550/two-uilabels-on-uitable-with-dynamic-height/37638748#37638748