# Multiline Label displaying extra empty spaces in table view cell in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I displayed multiline label in the table view using Autolayout. Everything is well but cell height is very much bigger than the label size.For example, if my label height is 100, cell height should be 100 because I am returning `heightForRowAtIndexPath` as label height but its height is returning as 150 etc.

Then I tried by removing `setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth` for that label, In that case, the last line of that label is not displaying(Truncating).

Comment: Show your code and snapshot of your tableview with result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally fixed that problem by adding following code in `cellForRowAtIndex`

```
    cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), 99999);
    cell.contentView.bounds = cell.bounds;
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    [cell.myLabel setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:CGRectGetWidth(cell.myLabel.frame)];
```

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947146/multiple-uilabels-inside-a-self-sizing-uitableviewcell)  for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 mytableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  mytableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
```

instead of returning height from heightForRowAtIndexPath.
And set all side autolayout constraint if your label height is dynamic. Set label's Lines property to zero.
If u want label and cell height same then set leading, trailing, top, bottom constraint to zero without margin.