# Strange behavior on scroll UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, autolayout, xcode6

I have a single view with nested scroll and table view with this hierarchical tree:

[image: Tree of the view]

*(The table is loaded with some Huckleberry Finn rows taken from this [example](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/02/14/table-view-cells-with-varying-row-heights.html).)*

On viewWillAppear I programmatically scroll the Table View at the last row doing

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self.tableView reloadData];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1 inSection:0];
   [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                              animated:YES];
}
```

and **everything works as expected**, in both orientation. As you can see, the text is rightly truncated.

[image: portrait]
[image: landscape]

I've uploaded on Github my project so you can see it running. Download it [here](https://github.com/rikiriocma/scrolltabletest).

Now, if you add this line in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;
```

the cells automatically will resize to embed and show the entire text label:

[image: numberOfLines=0]

BUT, and this is the issue my dear friends, as you can see **the table is not scrolled to the last row but 5-6 rows above**. And I cannot understand why.

The same thing happens also if NumberOfLines is 2,3 and so on. Only a value of 1 can make the TableView move down to the very last row.

*(FYI, I do not use `[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];` in order to scroll down the table because it throws an exception)*

Maybe something is wrong with iOS8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### viewDidLayoutSubviews will do the job

I guess you use some autolayout or self sizing cells? In `viewWillAppear` the calculation is not finished. So you scroll to the bottom, but then thereafter autolayout resizes your cells what makes them expand in height.

> For Details: [Refer to apple documentation UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html)
>
> ... "Your view controller can override this method to make changes after the view lays out its subviews. The default implementation of this method does nothing."

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Yes it is true you are right it could be the reason since I'm using autolayout. But what can I do to be sure? Is there any other method other than `viewWillAppear` to try?

Comment: Maybe you can tryy viewDidAppear but i am not sure about that. There should be some event like viewDidFinishedAutolayout. I will edit my answer if i can find something like that.

Comment: No, unfortunately "viewDidFinishedAutolayout" don't exists. I resolved using "viewDidLayoutSubview" as you can read below.

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubview is a good point to do that i think. i misunderstood the documentation about that method. but now i think it will do the work. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I added this event with reloadSection method and now the table scroll to the end. Also, I changed "tableView" to "myTableView" since I read that is better to give a non-default name to the views (as Sapi says in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995573/)).

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [self.myTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.myTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1 inSection:0];
    [self.myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                              animated:YES];
}
```

IMHO this thing is very Machiavellian, however.