# UILabel incorrectly sized in UITableViewCell (Animation after assigning text)

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

The text in a `UILabel` is flickering after being displayed, first appearing with ellipsis on a single line, then occupying the 2 lines it fits in.
Notice that the cell height doesn't change.

[image: UILabel wrap]

Here is the problem:
The label "Друзъя, примите участие и наполните Коробку!" (*Friends, take part and fill the boxes!*) first appears **truncated** and misaligned as "Друзъя, примите участи..." during the view transition.

[image: animation]

This happens only on iPhone 4s with iOS 8.1. All manipulation with Label (except text assigning) happens in the Storyboard.

What is causing this flickering?

Comment: What's the problem/question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are changing the test in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and further assuming this does not happen with all strings, only some with certain length, then this is an iOS bug.

See lengthy discussion on [this Stack Overflow `UITableViewCell` post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995573/dequeued-uitableviewcell-has-incorrect-layout-until-scroll-using-autolayout/35236138#35236138), and a possible workaround:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.setNeedsLayout()
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

---

**Notes**

**1.** I have also noticed that using a small value for `estimatedRowHeight` such as `20`, which is not as tall as the smallest cell, in combination with the doubled `reloadData()` was also beneficial.

**2.** You will need to invoke an extra `reloadData()` prior `setNeedsLayout()` when changing the cell width, such as toggling `tableView.editing`

**3.** A robust alternative to tinkering with a label is to use a *non Editable, non Selectable, none Capitalization, noScrolling enabled, no Show Horizontal & Vertical Indicator, no Bounce* `UITextView`.

---

*Exercise this bug, and try out the various workarounds:*

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-35260912) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-35260912).

Comment: Yusss! Thanks, it works! I wonder how this solution was discovered.

Comment: Painfully and very carefully