# Issue with UILabel center text alignment at different font sizes in Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, optimization, fonts

> This is an issue with UILabel in iOS7 and iOS8, it does not
>   present in iOS9. This odd UILabel behaviour is experienced with
>   different fonts, in Xcode versions 6 and 7 with Swift, using the
>   simulator and device.

Problem:

I have a UILabel that has a center text alignment. At different font sizes, some lines of text stop being center aligned and snap to left alignment. It is subtle but noticeable.

In the images below:

LEFT: all lines of text are centered neatly.

MIDDLE: after increasing the font size, the third line from the top snaps more to the left instead of remaining centered. (Notice more blue space on right.)

RIGHT: after increasing the font size a little more, both the second and third line from the top snap to the left instead of remaining centered. (Notice more blue space on right.)

[image]

Questions:

1. What explains what might be the cause of this unusual alignment behaviour in iOS7 and iOS8 but not iOS9?
2. How can I ensure that all lines are forced to remain center aligned perfectly regardless of the font type or font size used?
3. What is the bug fix or work around for this in iOS7 and iOS8 so that apps created using UILabel centre aligned don’t feature the bug?

Comment: [This same question was already asked once then deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291940/uilabel-center-text-alignment-issue-at-different-font-sizes-in-xcode-swift).

Comment: What is the lineBreakMode set on these labels?

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: @Kyle Redfearn , line break = Word Wrap.

Comment: @TroyT , yes storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

## Use `UITextView`

With all due respect, it is my experience that `UILabel` is plagued with bugs when it comes to multiple lines (Line count other than `1`).
Starting, but not limited to sizing cells containing such labels hardly able to predict its footprint<sup>**1**</sup>.

Use `UITextView`, non *editable*, scrolling *disabled* (that is the key). You will achieve the same effects, with more control over the final appearance.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> See note 3 on [this Stack Overflow `UILabel` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35261287/218152).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, UITextField doesn’t seem to work in this case but you have pointed me in another direction. (UITextField vertical center aligns but seems to only be limited to only a single line. I tried UITextView, that does multiple lines but t doesn’t vertical center align.) I've narrowed this down to an issue with UILabel that presents itself in iOS7 and iOS8, but does not present in iOS9.

Comment: Of course, my bad. I meant `UITextView` all along! Fixed the answer and added link.